# Webrtc GetUserMedia Firefox sharing a specific window

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, geckofx

I am creating an app which shares a specific window using WebRTC stream from Firefox browser.

I want to select this specific window. Is there a way to write the window Title Name or id in the media constraints to be able to capture only this Window?

```
           mediaConstraints = {
                    audio: audioOption,
                    video: {
                        mediaSource: "window",
                        frameRate: { ideal: 30 }
                    }
```

What I want to do **Like** :

```
               mediaConstraints = {
                    audio: audioOption,
                    video: {
                        mediaSource: "window",
                        windowTitle:<Title>,
                        frameRate: { ideal: 30 }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed as it would allow a website to enumerate your open windows. The [specification](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/#display-constraints) does not provide a way to enumerate windows for that reason too.

Comment: so if somehow I am able to get list of Windows I will not be able to enforce webrtc to capture this window?